# Contact adress book on Oreo shares a .vcf file instead of URI with lookup key

Tags: android, android-contacts

On **Android Oreo** and below I get following format:

```
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/as_vcard/967i4519d3b389d66e0f
```

*The last URI Path Segment ist here the contact lookup key.*

On **Android Pie** the contact app shares the contact via a VCF file like this:

```
content://com.google.android.contact.files/my_cache/contactname.vcf
```

Sadly there is no lookup key anymore. How can I get now the shared contact from the contact address book?

Comment: "The last URI Path Segment ist here the contact lookup key" -- not necessarily. How are you getting this `Uri`?

Comment: I get this from the standard google contact app via intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)!

Comment: So... you are getting this via `ACTION_SEND`? If so, how were you planning on forcing users to use "the standard google contact app"? What happens if they do not have that app?

Comment: Yes via ACTION_SEND. I have tested it at the moment only with the standard google contact app. I don't know yet how other apps share the contact.

Comment: Do not make assumptions about the structure of a `Uri` from an arbitrary app. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the content, and get the MIME type of that content from the `Intent`. If you want the user to pick a contact, start an `ACTION_PICK` activity from your app, using `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: I already check the MIME Type and it is text/x-vcard. But with Oreo the last pathsegment is the lookup key. So I used this. But you are right if I parse both with openInputStream I get on both a v-card. Thanks to point me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Also on Android **Oreo** it is a vcard, so don't use the last path segment only.

**As mentioned from CommonsWare:**
Do not make assumptions about the structure of a Uri from an arbitrary app. Use ContentResolver and openInputStream() to read in the content, and get the MIME type of that content from the Intent

**So the solution is:**
Check for the MIME Type with

```
intent.getType()
```

If it is **text/x-vcard** open it via openInputStream and parse the file.